# python histogram of the y value with equal number of data(x) in each bin

Tags: python, pandas, plot, histogram

I got a 2-columns dataframe (volume and price), and I want to create 20 bins based on the volume column with equal amount of data in each bin.

I.e. if I got volume = [1,6,8,2,6,9,3,6] and 4 bins, I want to cut the data to 1st bin: 1:2, 2nd: 3:6, 3rd: 6:8, 4th: 8:9

then to plot a histogram of the average corresponding y values

my data：

```
df = pd.DataFrame{'Volume_norm' : [0.92, 2.31, 0.92, 0.018, 0.0454, 0.43, 0.43,0.943,0.543,0.543,0.43] , 'Price' : [2, 4, 5, 1, 5, 1, 2, 4, 2, 3, 6]}
```

[image]

my code:

```
    x = sorted(FilteredTrade_buy['Volume_norm'])
bins=x[0::int(len(x)/50)]
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, bins=bins)
plt.show()
```

which only gives me the sum of x (volume) instead of the average y price

===============update code==============

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Volume_norm' : [0.92,2.31,0.92,0.018,0.0454,0.43,0.43,0.943,0.543,0.543,0.43], 
                   'Price' : [2,4,5,1,5,1,2,4,2,3,6]})

x = df['Volume_norm']
y = df['Price']
nbins = 5
binsize = x.size // nbins
indices = x.argsort()
means = np.zeros((nbins,))
xaxis = np.zeros((nbins,))
for k in range(nbins):
    xaxis[k] = x[indices[i * binsize : (i + 1) * binsize]].mean()
for i in range(nbins):
    means[i] = y[indices[i * binsize : (i + 1) * binsize]].mean()
plt.loglog(xaxis,means,'r-')
plt.show()
```

but xaxis returns me: array([ 0.9315,  0.9315,  0.9315,  0.9315,  0.9315])

furthermore, would it be possible to use 'Counter' to count the number of data in each interval?

Comment: Can you please add your data as text please? It isn't easy copying data from a picture.

Comment: Wait, so you want the height of the histogram bins, populated by `x`, to reflect the average `y` value? That isn't a histogram at all so you shouldn't use the `hist` function which assumes the standard definition of "histogram". Maybe just calculate the `y`-averages and plot the data with a `plt.plot()` call

Comment: question edited (date = df); and yes I tried to bin the data in plt.plot but it turned out that some of the boundary/edge of the bins are the same, therefore the 'cut' function is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an indirect sort of your data based on the x-values (`volume`), and then compute the average over each successive bin of the same size of your y-data (`price`).

```
nbins = 20
binsize = volume.size // nbins
indices = volume.argsort()
means = np.zeros((nbins,))
for i in range(nbins):
    means[i] = price[indices[i * binsize : (i + 1) * binsize]].mean()
```

You can reshape the `price` array and then compute the mean along an axis, too (i.e., `price[indices].reshape(nbins, -1).mean(axis=-1)`). This will be faster, but requires that you have exactly the same amount of data in each bin. The loop will handle the case when the last bin is not the same size as the others.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Can you please see the update part of the question as I want to compute the average for the volume as well and plot it as the x-axis. However I got a trouble with computing the average x for each bin

Comment: @bing It looks like you're using `i` inside the first for-loop, where it is not yet defined. You can compute the average x- and y-values inside the same loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but may I ask what is the function of 'argsort()' in this case?

Comment: @bing `np.argsort()` does an "argument sort". It returns an array of indices that will sort the original array. So `indices[0]` gives the index of the smallest value in `volume`, `indices[1]` the next value, and so forth.